# define index types in neo4j.properties

Tags: neo4j

I couldn't find the syntax to define the following index types in neo4j.properties. Can somebody provide some examples?

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html

Also, what exactly is the behavior difference between "exact" and "fulltext"?

Answer (score 0):

In neo4j.properties you only specify if you want autoindexing or not for the nodes / relantionships. If you need to change the default ('exact') configuration for this ones, you have to do it at runtime via REST: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html

Fulltext indexing will split the indexed value into words so you can query each word individually.

Comment: Does it mean that if I use "exact" on strings, I can't even do substring matching?

Comment: You can use the * in your query

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Can you provide links or examples?

Comment: Let's say you have the following phrase to index: 'my neo4j account'. If you use exact indexing, you can only search for 'my neo4j account' or use the * at the end (I think it works, never tried it) 'my neo4j acc*'. If you have a fulltext index you can query for 'neo4j' for instance or any other word in your phrase.